# Indices Missing from index_process table

Tags: magento-enterprise, indexing, enterprise-1.14

Having recently installed the Algoliasearch module on a client's site, I've found that its indices are missing from the `index_process` table. This was not an issue we had on any QA environments nor dev.

Following the module installation, we ran all install and upgrade scripts, cleared cache, and reindexed. Updating all indices (`n98-magerun.phar index:reindex:all`) *does* reindex the Algolia ones, but getting a list of indices and viewing them on admin doesn't show them.

It seems pretty clear that some standard action that adds these didn't run, but I'm not sure what should. It's *also* possible to take the rows from a different environment that correspond to Algolia indices and add them to the table (the `indexer_code` is really the most important and a known value)

Has this happened to anyone else? How can I resolve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that `sys:setup:run` will identify modules with version changes and run their updates, but it won't run `Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup::applyAllUpdates` which itself will trigger `Mage_Index_Model_Resource_Setup::applyUpdates` which calls `Mage_Index_Model_Resource_Setup::_syncIndexes`.

This discovery makes me wonder about how realistic it is to rely on Magerun to run migrations. If anyone has more detailed information on the issue, please leave it here!